# how to unzip a zipped directory in samsung bada after downloading it from server

Tags: c++, bada

We are developing a bada application in which we are downloading a zipped directory having JSON files and images in it. 
After downloading the zip file from server we need to extract it for reading.

I am looking for some native function or external library to implement the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Bada 2.0 introduced [FileUnzipper](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Base_1_1Utility_1_1FileUnzipper.html).

For previous Bada versions, you should take a look at [bada-zlib](https://bitbucket.org/arkadi/bada-zlib).